# Coverage of NodeJS using Karma

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, code-coverage, karma-runner, browserify

I try to get coverage from my project. Due to my IDE (IntelliJ) I'm using `Karma` with `mocha`. To make the tests run in karma I also added `browserify`. But I just get coverage of the tests not of the actual code:

[image]

Here is my `karma.conf.js`:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["mocha", "browserify"],
    files: [
      "test/**/*Test.js"
    ],
    exclude: [
        "src/Main.js"
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      "test/**/*Test.js": ["browserify"],
      "src/**/*.js": ['coverage']
    },
    reporters: ["progress", "coverage"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["Chrome"],
    singleRun: false,
    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      transform: [ "browserify-shim" ]
    }
  });
};
```

And an excerpt from my `package.json`:

```
{
  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "nssocket": "^0.5.3",
    "winston": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^10.2.4",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.8",
    "karma": "^0.12.36",
    "karma-browserify": "^4.2.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.4.2",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.1.10",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {}
}
```

I've tried to add all the code-files to the `karma.conf.js`→`files[]` but then I get various `Uncaught TypeError` by browserify:

```
files: ["src/**/*.js", ...
preprocessors: {"src/**/*.js": ["browserify"], ...
```

**UPDATE:**

I created two test-files, but they have no coverage:

**`test/TestTest.js`**

```
"use strict";

var assert = require("assert");
var test = require('../src/Interface/Test.js');

describe("Test", function () {

    describe("Test test, 5", function () {
        it("Test true 5", function () {
            assert.equal(test.addOneOnTrue(true, 5), 6);
        });

        it("Test false", function () {
            assert.equal(test.addOneOnTrue(false, 5), 5);
        });
    });
});
```

**`src/Test.js`**

```
var Test = function() {
    this.addOneOnTrue = function (boolean, int) {
        if(boolean) {
            ++int;
        }
        return int;
    }
};

module.exports = new Test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Change the preprocessor pattern for `coverage` to match `src` explicitly:

  ```
  "src/**/*.js": ["coverage"]
  ```
- Restart karma
- Check the report

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the line but I still get no Coverage. I just created two test-files and added them here to assure that these are not the proble (these run successfully).